# How to get MATLAB to recognise newly added static methods?

Tags: oop, matlab, function, scope

I am using classes and static methods to 'scope' functions in a namespace, similar to C#. However, every time I add a new method to a class, at first it is not found. I have to restart the MATLAB environment (2007a) for the new methods to be recognised.

Surely there is an 'update' or 'refresh' type command that I can use so that I do not have to restart the MATLAB environment each time I add a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issuing this call to [CLEAR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html) should do it:

```
clear classes
```

One unfortunate side effect of this is that it also effectively issues a **clear all**, which clears all of the variables in the workspace as well (however, this would happen anyway when you close and restart MATLAB). This clearing of the workspace actually serves a purpose, since it will remove any variables of the same type as the *old* version of your class, which potentially wouldn't work correctly with the *new* version of your class.

<strike>The function [REHASH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/rehash.html) *may* work, but I doubt it (I think it deals more with file paths than class definitions).</strike>

Comment: That does work, thanks! Is it possible though to do this on an individual class?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to use CLEAR to update individual classes that have been modified. It's all or none! =)

Comment: Tried rehash, none of the options work. Think that clear classes is the only way, cheers!

Comment: I don't know since which release it is, but now [it should suffice to clear all class instances](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brzqjky.html)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing instances of your class should work.

Suppose that you have an instance of "MyClass" in your base workspace:

```
foo = MyClass;
```

Now, suppose you edit MyClass and add new static method "bar":

```
foo.bar(); % Will cause error, as foo is instance of previous "MyClass"
```

However, "clear"-ing foo will remove the reference to the previous class:

```
clear('foo');
foo = MyClass; 
foo.bar(); % this should now work.
```

This should be fine if you only have one or two instances of the class in your base workspace. If you have many instances of the class in your base workspace, then you may want to write a script to clear them:

```
varList = whos;
for iVar = 1:numel(varList)
    if isequal( 'MyClass', varList(iVar).class )
        clear( varlist(iVar).name );
    end
end
clear('varList');
clear('MyClass');
```

If you have instances of the class in more locations, you may wish to extend the script as appropriate.

The last call to clear the class name might only be necessary if you are making modifications to classes in an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: see also http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brzqjky.html which also lists instances one might easily forget about (e.g. in `mlocked` functions)

Answer (score 0):

try "clear classname"

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, it accepts it without error but the class is not updated

Comment: This [should work with more recent versions of MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brzqjky.html)